# Merging two lines of numbers using regex?

Tags: regex

I have two lines of numbers. How to take lowerline number and add it to end of upperline number. There should also be ^ -character between numbers.

```
2 2 2 2  
0 6 12 18
```

It should look like this:

```
2^0 2^6 2^12 2^18
```

Comment: Regex alone won't be able to do this. What tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: What language/tool you're using?

Comment: *two lines of numbers* Is it array of numbers or string?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your lines contain exactly 4 numbers, you can use the following match/replace :

```
match         (\d+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+)\R(\d+) (\d+) (\d+) (\d+)
replace by    \1^\5 \2^\6 \3^\7 \4^\8
```

This matches two lines, capturing the 8 numbers each in their own capturing group, replacing the two lines by a line constructed from the 8 numbers.

If the amount of numbers on each line can vary this is not something you can handle with regex.

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/1e7UuL/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
var nums1 = new[] { 2, 2, 2, 2 };
var nums2 = new[] { 0, 6, 12, 18 };
var s = nums1.Zip(nums2, (x1, x2) => $"{x1}^{x2}");
s.ToList().ForEach(WriteLine);
```

Same logic could be adapted for strings.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is overkill, use an array methods like [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) if you need it as a string.

### Demo

```js
// If the inputs are strings
var dos = '2, 2, 2, 2';
var seis = '0, 6, 12, 18';

// split() will break a string intoan array
var two = dos.split(', ');
var six = seis.split(', ');

// map() will run a function on each element of an array
var twoSix = two.map(function(t, i) {
  return t + '^' + six[i];
});

// join() will connect all of an array's elements into a string
var str = twoSix.join(', ');

// This is to display better in console
var arr = JSON.stringify(twoSix);

console.log('An array: ' + arr + ' ...');
console.log('... or a string: ' + str);
```